# Could Ant-Man's suit create a black hole?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, physics, ant-man, ant-man-2015

The theory of general relativity published by Albert Einstein in 1915 states that a sufficiently compact mass can deform spacetime to form a black hole.

Black holes are therefore nothing more than an accumulation of mass so strong that it's actually able to draw everything to itself, including radiation and electromagnetic waves.

Since all the suit does is shrinking the owner's body, but not depriving it of its mass, is it possible for the black hole to occur, cause of the accumulation of mass in a small space?

Comment: He'd have to shrink [to a size significantly smaller than atomic nuclei](https://www.britannica.com/science/Schwarzschild-radius).

Comment: But it's possible nevertheless

Comment: Well, everything is possible in the comic universe, so then the premise of the question doesn't make sense. I'm telling that it's impossible in the real world, because, apparently, you can't compress matter to those dimensions.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-MhE0J9Tx8

Comment: Thanks man! I'm so ashamed I haven't yet seen this clip!

Comment: In real-world physics, a human-sized mass would become a black hole around 1e-25 meters; that's smaller than _an electron_ but still much larger than the Plank length; relativity starts to break down _somewhere_ in between those two. So, "maybe"?

Comment: I think if this question was changed to 'has he ever' it would have some merit. If you are interested in real science micro black holes look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole

Comment: Imagine your body mass were supported by a pair of teeny-tiny ant-feet. You would be leaving teeny-tiny footprints everywhere - probably even in solid concrete (much like stiletto heels can damage a wood floor). So - does ant-man leave teeny-tiny footprints everywhere he walks? No. So there must be something going on with his mass when he shrinks...

Answer (score 8):

Comic Science and common sense don't go hand in hand!

Ant-Man doesn't use Relativistic Physics to shrink (or Enlarge) himself. He uses an imaginary particle known as Pym Particles! Thus the "real world physics" doesn't affect him. He could shrink indefinitely (like in the movie) and wouldn't create a black hole.

For more on Pym Particles: [Pym Particles](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Pym_Particles)

Now to answer the exact question, Could he create a black hole?
The answer is that ***It Depends***. It depends on the plot and the story the next writer wants to write and if he wants to add creation of black holes in the Ant Man's repertoire. (He doesn't need to shrink himself, just pick any random object)

Comment: in the movie I believe Hank specifically explains that Pym particles shrink matter without changing the mass, so it _should_ still have an eventually lower limit.

Answer (score 1):

> Since all the suit does is shrinking the owner's body, **but not depriving it of its mass**, is it possible for the black hole to occur, cause of the accumulation of mass in a small space?

When Ant-Man shrinks, his mass doesn't remain constant. You can see it in the movie. He can ride ants. While ants can carry impressive amounts of mass, they have trouble carrying us (try stepping on an ant; talk to animal activists first). With Ant-Man so small and mass 60 Kg, his weight will actually crush any ant badly.

**So where does the mass go?**
Pym Particles push mass into "Kosmos Dimension" while shrinking Ant-Man and pop mass from the same while enlarging.

[image]
<sub><sub>(Source: Thunderbolts (1997) #13)</sub></sub>

According to Hank Pym's scientific article "Ha, Ha I'm Giant-Man Now: Screw you, All other Physicists", Pym Particles also violate Galileo's [Square-Cube Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-cube_law) which is one of the bases of Einstein's General Theory of Relativity.
<sub><sub>(Source: Unbeatable Squirrel Girl Vol. 2 #14 (2017))</sub></sub>

Comment: I am not talking to an animal activist before I kill an ant!

Answer (score -2):

Making rough assumptions I suppose you can create small black hole with the Pym suit. Lets assume that a man of m = 80 kg shrinks down to a size of hydrogen atom (Rh = 1.2*10^-10 m). On his surface he would create gravitational pull of G*m/Rh^2 = 372.2*10^10^9 m*s^(-2).

I do not know how exactly massive objects bend space as light travels in minimal distance through bent space and that is the reason for it circling the black hole, but I suppose such gravitational pull should be more than enough to bend space properly to trap light.

P.S. Small black holes, in that case as small as hydrogen atom would evaporate very fast. I Have not read many Ant Man comics, but the fact should definitely occur to writers, and I suppose there should be threshold where Ant Man's mass starts to decrease as he continues to shrink.